# if statement with modulo operator inside for loop

Tags: c, if-statement, modulo

```
int i;
for(i=10;i<=20;i=i+2)
    if(i%10 <= 5)
        printf("hello\n");
```

Why is "hello" printed four times? I expected it to be three times. Is it because of precedence?

Comment: Step through the code, statement by statement, and see what it does.

Comment: `printf("hello %d\n", i);` would reveal it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the loop exit condition, which is `<=` rather than the more common `<`. The printout is triggered for `i` values of `10`, `12`, `14`, and also `20`.